# How to set the frequency (2.4 or 5 GHz) of WiFi hotspot via command line in Windows?

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, command-line, windows-server

For some reason, I need to enable WiFi hotspot on a machine running Windows Server 2019.

Unlike Windows 10, there is no native GUI to enable hotspot in settings, so I need to run this code in cmd / PS:

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=foo key=barbarbar
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
```

The model of the WiFi card is [Atheros AR5B22](https://wikidevi.com/wiki/Atheros_AR5B22) (aka WB222: Atheros AR9462 - DB 2x2 Wi-Fi + BT 4.0). Like what is described in [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1129609/why-cant-my-windows-10-create-2-4g-wifi-hotspot), there is a strange problem in this card (I don't know if it's due to my personal reasons):

- It CAN connect to both 2.4G and 5G network
- It CAN create working 5GHz WiFi hotspot
- Created 2.4GHz hotspot shows normal but no signal

This happens on all versions of drivers (Microsoft's or official whql drivers).

---

Now I can create 5GHz hotspot ONLY BY connect to a 2.4GHz network first.

Is there any way to set the frequency of hotspot via command line, before `netsh wlan start hostednetwork`?

Comment: Could you clarify: How is your computer connected to the Internet (Ethernet etc)? How many network adapters does it have? Please specify in detail the procedure you use now to set the hotspot to 5GHZ.

Comment: There is a Intel Gigabit adapter (82579LM) apart from the AR5B22 adapter. The computer is connected by Ethernet, which shares to the hotspot.

Comment: Please specify in detail the procedure you use now to set the hotspot to 5GHZ.

Comment: Since it's a dual band adapter, when connected to a 2.4G WiFi, the 2.4GHz channel should be occupied, and the free 5G band can be set for hotspot.